# Editable Label And Checkbox Not Working In GrapesJs With React

Tags: reactjs, grapesjs

I am working on grapesjs and Building a custom block. The Problem is that I Want to make the checkbox workable and label to be editable when someone clicks on it. I tried to read documentation of grapesjs and other google stuff but it didn't work :(

Here Is My Code Of Block

```
import Icon from "../../assets/images/icons8-form-100.png";

export default function upsell(editor, options) {
  // // creating new trait for form plugin
  // editor.DomComponents.addType("input", {
  //   // isComponent: (el) => el.tagName === "INPUT",
  //   model: {
  //     defaults: {
  //       traits: [
  //         {
  //           type: "text", // If you don't specify the type, the `text` is the default one
  //           name: "actionUrl", // Required and available for all traits
  //           label: "Action Url", // The label you will see near the input
  //           // label: false, // If you set label to `false`, the label column will be removed
  //           placeholder: "Enter URL", // Placeholder to show inside the input
  //           changeProp: 1,
  //         },
  //       ],

  //       // As by default, traits are binded to attributes, so to define
  //       // their initial value we can use attributes
  //       attributes: { type: "text", required: true },
  //     },
  //   },
  // });

  // creating new block
  editor.BlockManager.add("#editor", {
    label: `<div>
    <img src=${Icon} width="50" style="filter:invert(1)" />
    <h3>Upsell</h3>
    </div>`,
    content: {
      // type: "input",
      content: `<div class="upsell-comp">
      <input data-gjs-editable="true" id="chkUpsell" name="chkUpsell" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="upsell">Add On Size With Just $1!</label>
      </div>`,
    },
  });

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue Solved By Using grapesjs-plugin-forms package